# Storing curl session cookies in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, curl

I was wondering if it was possible to store a curl's session cookie inside of mysql.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, get_the_cookie());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, get_the_cookie());
```

get_the_cookie() returns a unique-to-user.txt file path,
but I want to be able to store this cookie in a mysql instead of the file-system if its even possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cURL does not allow you to do this directly, but you can fake it by creating temporary files for the duration of the request and manually transferring their contents from/to the database as needed.

For example:

```
$cookiejar = // get cookies from database
$cookiejarfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir());
$cookiefile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir());
file_put_contents($cookiejarfile, $cookiejar);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiejarfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);

$newcookies = file_get_contents($cookiefile);

// and now save cookies to database and clean up temp files
```